# Do these two reactions with photons have the same chemical potential?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

The reactions in question are:

$$e^+ + e^- \longleftrightarrow \gamma$$

$$e^+ + e^- \longleftrightarrow \gamma + \gamma$$

We have two different systems to compare with each other, both composed of electrons and positrons. In one system we only get the first reaction, and in the second system we only get the second reaction.
Would these two reactions have the same chemical equilibrium?

The reason I think they are is because the chemical potentials would have to be

$$\mu_{e^+} + \mu_{e^-} = \mu_\gamma=0$$

$$\mu_{e^+} + \mu_{e^-} = \mu_\gamma + \mu_\gamma = 0 + 0 = 0$$

but I think this is a weird result.

Comment: What do you mean by the two reactions having the same chemical equilibrium, when you posit that the reactions happen in different independent systems?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by two different systems to compare with each other. I found the problem though (check my comment to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

When an electron and a positron annihilate, they can’t produce a lone photon, so your question is meaningless.

To see that they can’t produce a lone photon, consider the interaction in the frame where the electron and positron have equal and opposite momentum. Since momentum is conserved, the photon would have to be at rest, but this is impossible for a massless particle.

Comment: I think it is just because I misunderstood the statement. I found out that (where I read it) the $\gamma$ in $e^+ + e^- \longleftrightarrow \gamma$ just meant arbitrary photon(s).